# SQL query varchar concatenation when doing joins

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm writing a webservice to query information from a database and put it into a JSONArray. I have one table called CLIENT and another table called CLIENT_NOTES that holds a date and notes about a client. There can be multiple CLIENT_NOTES entries for a client, but not the other way around.

So my query is:

```
SELECT      c.CLIENT_NAME, cn.NOTE_DATE, cn.CONTENT 
FROM        CLIENT          c
LEFT JOIN   CLIENT_NOTES    cn  ON c.CLIENT_ID = cn.CLIENT_ID
ORDER BY    c.CLIENT_NAME
```

Currently, I get multiple rows per client if they have multiple note entries.

How do I change my query so that I always get one row per client and the NOTE_DATE CONTENT columns can be combined into a concatenated string with newline characters in between.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group your results and apply the [`group_concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT      c.CLIENT_NAME, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(cn.NOTE_DATE SEPARATOR '\n'), 
            GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(cn.CONTENT, '%d-%m-%y') SEPARATOR '\n')
FROM        CLIENT          c
LEFT JOIN   CLIENT_NOTES    cn  ON c.CLIENT_ID = cn.CLIENT_ID
GROUP BY    c.CLIENT_NAME
ORDER BY    c.CLIENT_NAME
```

Comment: Thank you. I should mention that NOTE_DATE is a timestamp field and not a varchar field. Your GROUP_CONCAT solution works perfectly on the  CONTENT varchar field, but the \n separator doesn't seem to register on the timestamp field. It appends, but it doesn't create a new line. Any suggestions?

Comment: @WilliamRoberts You can format the date to a string - see edited answer

Answer (score 1):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT c.CLIENT_NAME, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(cn.NOTE_DATE AS CHAR) SEPARATOR '\n'), 
GROUP_CONCAT(cn.CONTENT SEPARATOR '\n')
FROM CLIENT c
LEFT JOIN CLIENT_NOTES cn ON c.CLIENT_ID = cn.CLIENT_ID
GROUP BY c.CLIENT_NAME
ORDER BY c.CLIENT_NAME
```